# Create function inside function to send e-mail

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have a problem with functions. I create functions to send e-mails. I'm trying to create function, for example: I call function with variable ($product_id), and depends on this product id, I would like to send e-mails.

```
<?php
$product_id = 2000;
echo select_users_to_send($product_id);

function get_product_type($id_product){
    // Define product group
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT n_products.Product_Group
FROM tsales_funnel_mrecord
LEFT JOIN n_products on tsales_funnel_mrecord.Product_type = n_products.Product_Code
WHERE ID = $id_product";
    $type_product = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
    return $type_product;
}
function select_users_to_send($type = get_product_type($product_id)){
    return $type.' user';
}

?>
```

I wrote this code, but it didn't works for me. Shows error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

Maybe there need to use classes? But I didn't understand how to write classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function select_users_to_send($product_id){
  $type = get_product_type($product_id)
  return $type.' user';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

> This code solved the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(',
>   expecting ')'"

```
<?php
$product_id = 2000;
echo select_users_to_send($product_id);

function get_product_type($id_product){
    // Define product group
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT n_products.Product_Group
FROM tsales_funnel_mrecord
LEFT JOIN n_products on tsales_funnel_mrecord.Product_type = n_products.Product_Code
WHERE ID = $id_product";

    $type_product = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

    return $type_product;
}

// getting output from the function
$type = get_product_type($product_id);

// passing the $type var
function select_users_to_send($type){
    return $type.' user';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create class like this. But You can solved your issue using first answer, This is only example for your knowledge for classes

select_user.php

```
    class select_user{
    # Start function get_product_type
    function get_product_type($id_product){
        // Define product group
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT n_products.Product_Group
        FROM tsales_funnel_mrecord
        LEFT JOIN n_products on tsales_funnel_mrecord.Product_type = n_products.Product_Code
        WHERE ID = $id_product";
        $type_product = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
        return $type_product;
    } 
    # Start function select_users_to_send

    function select_users_to_send($product_id){
        $type = get_product_type($product_id);
        return $type.' user';
    }
}# End Class
```

Now create PHP file for call to class

```
# include class file path
include ('select_user.php');
# create class object
$user_create = new select_user();

# Call methord of class class_name 
$product_id = 2000;

$return_val = $user_create->select_users_to_send($product_id);

echo $return_val;
```